# Folded 'using' section by default

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, resharper

Is there a way to set Visual Studio to have usings section collapsed by default? Every time I open a c# file, first thing I have to do is either hit a keystroke to fold all the regions or click to collapse usings. Maybe there's a checkbox in settings or some resharper's option that lets you have them collapsed by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer for this is to wrap my usings in a `#region`, which VS collapses by default.

```
#region using
using System;
using System.Linq;
#endregion using
```